# Como fazer if e else de entre 2 variáveis com saída em uma terceira?

Tags: php, variáveis, if, else

Peço imensa desculpa mas tive que reescrever toda a minha pergunta porque não estava a ser objectivo o suficiente para me fazer entender, quando omito código como era o caso anterior não é para esconder algo é só mesmo para poder perceber o que me respondem dentro das minhas limitações de programação, em todo o caso assim que a plataforma estiver pronta irei disponibiliza-la online.

Neste primeiro ficheiro estará disponível as variáveis para poderem ser alteradas para proceder as ligações entre os 3 servidores a demonstração é para o servidor 1.

```
#/pasta/config.php
<?PHP
//Atenção ao configurar este ficheiro pois é igual para os 3 servidores
//e terá que ter em mente em que servidor o esta a configurar
//porque tem que descomentar o $serverip correspondente e entre as aspas colocar o seu ip interno de sua rede
//e em $dbL colocar entre as aspas o numero correspondente ao servidor que escolheu 1, 2 ou 3.

$dbL = "1";// Que servidor é este? 1, 2 ou 3.

$serverip1  = "10.0.0.101";    // Ip interno Mysql se for o servidor 1
$db_porta1    = "3306";        // Porta Mysql servidor 1
$db_user1     = "dns";         // Utilizador Mysql servidor 1
$db_password1 = "123456";      // Senha Mysql servidor 1
$db_name1     = "dns";         // Nome base dados Mysql servidor 1

//$serverip2 = "10.0.0.102";   // Ip interno Mysql se for o servidor 2
$db_porta2    = "3306";        // Porta Mysql servidor 2
$db_user2     = "dns";         // Utilizador Mysql servidor 2
$db_password2 = "123456";      // Senha Mysql servidor 2
$db_name2     = "dns";         // Nome base dados Mysql servidor 2

//$serverip3 = "10.0.0.103";   // Ip interno Mysql se for o servidor 3
$db_porta3    = "3306";        // Porta Mysql servidor 3
$db_user3     = "dns";         // Utilizador Mysql servidor 3
$db_password3 = "123456";      // Senha Mysql servidor 3
$db_name3     = "dns";         // Nome base dados Mysql servidor 3
?>
```

Os 3 ficheiros seguintes são actualizados a cada 60 segundos e os ips já foram verificados antes de entrarem nos servidores.

```
#/pasta/connect/ipserver1.php
<?PHP $s_ipserver11 = "xx.246.142.235";?>

#/pasta/connect/ipserver2.php
<?PHP $s_ipserver22 = "xx.246.142.245";?>

#/pasta/connect/ipserver3.php
<?PHP $s_ipserver33 = "xx.246.142.255";?>
```

Para não estar a fazer 4 includes em todos os ficheiros que fizer falta criei o seguinte.

```
#/pasta/connect/ipservers.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/config.php");
include_once("/pasta/connect/ipserver1.php");
include_once("/pasta/connect/ipserver2.php");
include_once("/pasta/connect/ipserver3.php");
?>
```

Este será o ficheiro desta pergunta onde pretendo que dêem entrada de 2 variáveis ou não e com saída por uma terceira para cada ligação.

```
#/pasta/connect/convencao.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/connect/ipservers.php");
//Se existir variável $serverip1 ler valor se não ler valor de $s_ipserver11 mas se existirem as duas ler sempre $serverip1 e responder em $ip1.
//Se existir variável $serverip2 ler valor se não ler valor de $s_ipserver22 mas se existirem as duas ler sempre $serverip2 e responder em $ip2.
//Se existir variável $serverip3 ler valor se não ler valor de $s_ipserver33 mas se existirem as duas ler sempre $serverip3 e responder em $ip3.
if( isset( $serverip1 ) and isset( $s_ipserver11 ) )
{
$ip1 = $serverip1;
}
else
{
if( isset( $serverip1 ) )
$ip1 = $serverip1;
if( isset( $s_ipserver11 ) )
$ip1 = $s_ipserver11;
}

if( isset( $serverip2 ) and isset( $s_ipserver22 ) )
{
$ip2 = $serverip2;
}
else
{
if( isset( $serverip2 ) )
$ip2 = $serverip2;
if( isset( $s_ipserver22 ) )
$ip2 = $s_ipserver22;
}

if( isset( $serverip3 ) and isset( $s_ipserver33 ) )
{
$ip3 = $serverip3;
}
else
{
if( isset( $serverip3 ) )
$ip3 = $serverip3;
if( isset( $s_ipserver33 ) )
$ip3 = $s_ipserver33;
}

$s_ipserver1 = $ip1;
$s_ipserver2 = $ip2; //Coloquei estas 3 variáveis para dar a entender o que preciso mas podem ser apagadas.
$s_ipserver3 = $ip3;
?>
```

Abaixo estão as varias formas de ligação para dar a entender o que preciso.

Ligação ao servidor 1

```
#/pasta/connect/connectserver1.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/connect/convencao.php");
$db_host1     = "$s_ipserver1:$db_porta1";
$db_link1     = mysql_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect1  = mysql_select_db($db_name1, $db_link1);
?>
```

Ligação ao servidor 2

```
#/pasta/connect/connectserver2.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/connect/convencao.php");
$db_host2     = "$s_ipserver2:$db_porta2";
$db_link2     = mysql_connect($db_host2, $db_user2, $db_password2) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect2  = mysql_select_db($db_name2, $db_link2);
?>
```

Ligação ao servidor 3

```
#/pasta/connect/connectserver3.php
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/connect/convencao.php");
$db_host3     = "$s_ipserver3:$db_porta3";
$db_link3     = mysql_connect($db_host3, $db_user3, $db_password3) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect3  = mysql_select_db($db_name3, $db_link3);
?>
```

Variáveis para ligação ao servidor local

```
#/pasta/connect/connectserverLsub.php
<?php 
include_once("/pasta/connect/convencao.php");
$ipserver  = 's_ipserver'. $dbL;
$porta     = 'db_porta'. $dbL;
$user      = 'db_user'. $dbL;
$password  = 'db_password'. $dbL;
$name      = 'db_name'. $dbL;
?>
```

Ligação ao servidor local

```
#/pasta/connect/connectserverL.php
<?PHP
include_once("/rjpdns/connect/connectserverLsub.php");
$host         = $$ipserver . ':'. $$porta;
$link         = mysql_connect($host, $$user, $$password) or die (mysql_error ());
$db_connect   = mysql_select_db($$name, $link);
?>
```

Espero desta vez ter exposto e melhorado a minha duvida.

Comment: Não existe `break` para if.  Não ficou muito claro o que deseja.

Comment: @Rjp, em vez de escrever comentários, é melhor **[edit]** a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes.

Comment: Sim é verdade tem razão @brasofilo

Comment: É, porque se outra pessoa chegar, só tem que ler a pergunta pra entender o problema. Tem uma explicação sua que tá lá embaixo na resposta, e parece importante...

Comment: @Rjp Servidor, eu gostaria muito que voce conseguisse resolver seu problema, mas nao esta claro o que deseja. Voce diz que quer validar os ips pois podem estar errados, e no comentario do Manuel Gerardo Pereira voce diz: "sei que os ips são validos
isso não há duvida". Seja mais claro com o problema para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Pergunta reorganizada e muito mais completa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se é isso que você quer. É preciso saber de que tipo são os *$ip1 e $ip2* - se são bool ou se são os ips reais. Me diga para ajustar a questão.

**Opção 1:**

```
if( isset( $ip1 ) ){
    $ip3 = $ip1;
}elseif( isset( $ip2 ) ){
    $ip3 = $ip2;
}
```

---

**Opção 2:**

Note que se *$ip1 e $ip2* contiverem valor (diferente de null), sempre retornará o último if devido à sobreposição das condições de verdadeiro.

```
$ips = array( $ip1 , $ip2 );
foreach( $ips as $val )
{
    if( $val )
    $ip3 = $val;
}
```

---

**Opção 3:**

Resolvendo sobreposição em caso de dois ips verdadeiros.

```
if( isset( $ip1 ) and isset( $ip2 ) )
{
    // os dois estão corretos, vou usar o primeiro `ip-1`
    $ip3 = $ip1;
}
else
{
    if( isset( $ip1 ) ){
        $ip3 = $ip1;
    }elseif( isset( $ip2 ) ){
        $ip3 = $ip2;
    }
}
```

---

**Opção 4:**

Considero uma opção bem prática. Você terá a variável *$ips* com um array contendo os *$ip1 e $ip2* e depois basta usar *array_filter* para filtrar todos os valores que forem null, e o uso será o índice zero `$ips[0]` - o primeiro índice que contem um valor. Bem simples de usar.

```
$ip1 = 1;
$ip2 = 2;

$ips = array_filter( array( $ip1 , $ip2 ) );
$ip3 = $ips[0];
```

---

### Atualização seguindo instruções da edição do autor

```
// se existir $serverip1 e $s_ipserver11, usaremos $serverip1
if( isset( $serverip1 ) and isset( $s_ipserver11 ) )
{
    $ip1 = $serverip1;
}
else
{
    // se existir APENAS $serverip1
    if( isset( $serverip1 ) )
    $ip1 = $serverip1;

    // se existir APENAS $s_ipserver11
    if( isset( $s_ipserver11 ) )
    $ip1 = $s_ipserver11;
}
```

Comment: Os ips são reais quero dizer ou é o meu ip interno da minha rede ou o meu ip externo do meu provedor de qualquer maneira não sei ainda o que é bool. De qualquer maneira gostava que a selecção do ip fosse automática caso um estive-se errado ou seja o MYSQL não se consegui-se ligar.

Comment: Veja o que são tipos [*booleanos*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php). O meu exemplo #4 faz automaticamente o que você deseja, teste ele e veja o resultado.

Comment: O exemplo #4 irá funcionar mesmo que um ip já esteja desactualizado aleatoriamente?

Comment: Não funcionou @PapaCharlie. Acho que com o que aumentei na pergunta devo de me ter explicado melhor.

Comment: Não tinha percebido!! A sua actualização esta excelente mais uma vez muito obrigado.

Comment: É um modelo para *ip1*, use-o para *ip2 e ip3*. Se repara, a estrutura é a mesma do meu **exemplo #3**, bastava adaptar. Ia chamar você para o chat, mas sua reputação é baixa... Se isso resolve o problema marque a resposta?

Comment: Marcada e já alterei na pergunta o mérito e todo seu.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Tente ser sempre o mais claro possível quando perguntar, e se for preciso coloque um exemplo do que está fazendo, para evitar interpretação errada do problema. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer assim

```
    include_once("/pasta/ip1.php");
    include_once("/pasta/ip2.php");


    function validar_ips($ip1,$ip2){

         //verifica de o ip é válido
            $ip1 = (filter_var("111.111.111.111", FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) ? "111.111.111.111" : FALSE;
            //verifica se o ip é válido
            $ip2 = (filter_var("222.222.222.222", FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) ? "222.222.222.222" : FALSE;
            $ip3 = NULL;

            //se o ip não for válido então ip3 = ip2
            if(!$ip3=$ip1)
               $ip3=$ip2;

            //se nenhum dos ip for válido para a execução
            // aqui optei por filter_var para ter mesmo a certeza que tenho um ip válido
            if(!filter_var($ip3, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
             return NULL;

            return $ip3;
}

           $db_host1     = validar_ips($ip1,$ip2);
           $db_connect1  = mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1,$db_porta1) or die (mysqli_error ());
```

Comment: Eu sei que os ips são validos isso não há duvida agora não posso mexer nos ficheiros que tem os ips porque são actualizados por um sistema de sincronização.

Comment: Aqui não vai mexer em nada, apenas irá definir um ip válido que será guardado na variavel $ip3 , depois fará o que bem entender com esse valor. Entre ip1 e ou ip2 escolheu aquele que é válido. Guarda esse ip numa variavel chamada $ip3, de pois usa como entender.

Comment: veja a edição da resposta

Comment: Apenas uma dica, antes de usar uma variável, verifique sempre se o que está guardado nela é aquilo que espera. Aqui não tem absoluta certeza que o sistema de sincronização não cometeu qualquer erro na gravação.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você vai receber os 2 IPs, mas em determinado momento o IP 1, mesmo estando preenchido corretamente não vai responder a chamada de conexão mysql, então você deve tentar conectar com o IP 1 e em caso de erros tentar no IP 2, acho que algo assim deve servir:

```
<?PHP
include_once("/pasta/connect.php");

foreach(array($ip1,$ip2) as $db_host1) {
    $db_connect1 = @mysqli_connect($db_host1, $db_user1, $db_password1, $db_name1, $db_porta1);
    if ($db_connect1) break;
}

if (!$db_connect1) die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());

?>
```

Obs.: Testei aqui e funcinou bem, o único detalhe é que caso o IP 1 esteja invalido, há uma demora até ele passar para o IP 2. Veja se não é melhor você tentar o IP 2 primeiro e depois passar para o IP 1.

Comment: Se fizer a comparação lógica em vez do loop, talvez fique mais rápido : "se a conexão com o ip1 não deu faça com o ip2"

Comment: @ManuelGerardoPereira Como iria ficar mais rápido, se a demora se dá justamente pelo fato do mysqli ficar tentando conectar? loop ou if da na mesma... Talvez tentar implementar um timeout menor, não pude pesquisar sobre isso, deixo para o OP.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos ver se é isto que pretende. Para entender melhor, algumas considerações:

a) Em /pasta/config.php todas as veriaveis são caracteriticas de um *servidor* então é melhor agrupa-las numa array. Assim temos a certeza que todas pertencem ao mesmo servidor. Portanto fica assim:

```
$server1 = array(

   "serverip"  => "10.0.0.101",    // Ip interno Mysql se for o servidor 1
   "db_porta"    => "3306",        // Porta Mysql servidor 1
   "db_user"     => "dns",         // Utilizador Mysql servidor 1
   "db_password" => "123456",     // Senha Mysql servidor 1
   "db_name"     => "dns",

);

$server2 = array(

   "serverip"  => "10.0.0.102",    // Ip interno Mysql se for o servidor 1
   "db_porta"    => "3306",        // Porta Mysql servidor 1
   "db_user"     => "dns",         // Utilizador Mysql servidor 1
   "db_password" => "123456",     // Senha Mysql servidor 1
   "db_name"     => "dns",

);

$server3 = array(

   "serverip"  => "10.0.0.102",    // Ip interno Mysql se for o servidor 1
   "db_porta"    => "3306",        // Porta Mysql servidor 1
   "db_user"     => "dns",         // Utilizador Mysql servidor 1
   "db_password" => "123456",     // Senha Mysql servidor 1
   "db_name"     => "dns",

);
```

b) Quanto ao ficheiro /pasta/connect/convencao.php. O código repetido foi agrupado em funções. Eu tenho por norma, não confiar nos parâmetros dados para ter a certeza do saída da função. Por isso que , por mais que estranhe, voltei a verificar a validade dos ips. Aqui abro mão de performance e uso mais recursos, para ter consistência da saída.

c) não entendi bem pertende ligar ao primeiro servidor disponivel ou se um dos três não estiver disponivel ligar a um outro servidor. Conforme seja o caso acho que esta solução serve para as duas situações ou mais algumas. Com estás funções testa a possibilidade de ligar a qualquer servidor e pode depois usar a array de retorno para conexão á base de dados.

d) Não fiz debug do código.

```
/**
* vejo se consigo conectar a um servidor e guardo o ip na array de retorno. Se 
* conseguir *conectar gravo ao conexão e a tabela da array de retorno
*
* @param array $server - características do servidor
* @param string $ip_2 - ip alternativo
*
* @return array 
*/
function validar_ips(array $server, $ip_2) {

    #copio a array porque vai ser transformada
    $my_server = $server;

    #verifica de o ip é válido
    $ip1 = (filter_var($my_server['serverip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) ? $server['serverip'] : FALSE;

    #verifica se o ip é válido
    $ip2 = (filter_var($ip_2, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) ? $ip_2 : FALSE;

    $my_server['serverip'] = NULL;

    #se o ip1 não for válido então $my_server['serverip'] = ip2
    if (!$my_server['serverip'] = $ip1)
        $my_server['serverip'] = $ip2;

    #se nenhum dos ip for válido para a execução
    #aqui optei por filter_var para ter mesmo a certeza que tenho um ip válido
    if (!filter_var($my_server['serverip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        return NULL;

    if (!$my_server = conexao_servidor($my_server))
        return FALSE;

    // retorno uma nova array para fazer a ligação ao servidor local
    return $my_server;
}

/**
* conexão á base de dados
*
*/
function conexao_servidor(array $server) {

    $n_server = $server;

    $db_host = $n_server['serverip'] . ":" . $n_server['db_porta'];

    //já faço a ligação ao servidor. Retorno false em vez do erro que ligação por questões de segurança
    if (!$n_server['conexao'] = mysql_connect($db_host, $my_server['db_user'], $my_server['db_password']))
        return FALSE;

    //defino a base de dados
    $n_server['database'] = mysql_select_db($n_server['db_name'], $n_server['conexao']);

    return $n_server;
}

//Se não conseguir conectar com um, conectar alternativo.
if (!validar_ips($server1, $s_ipserver11))
    if (!validar_ips($server2, $s_ipserver2))
       if (!validar_ips($server3, $s_ipserver33))
           echo "não foi possivel ligar";
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu interesse @Manuel Gerardo Pereira mas como a plataforma que estou a desenvolver é para disponibilizar online terei que manter um config básico e fácil de configurar como se fosse eu a querer instalar pois muitas pessoas não tem qualquer conhecimento para se entenderem com um array tal como eu, sei e já disse que uma configuração com array terá que ser uma opcção no futuro mas terá que estar num sub ficheiro, em relação a "b)" a maior parte dos scripts são executados por cron e como pretendo executar alguns em muito poucos segundos não posso confirmar a mesma coisa 2 vezes.

Comment: Em relação a "c)" no config existe a variável $dbL que é o que vai dizer ao próprio servidor quem ele é e irá escolher algumas situações em relação a db e para se ligar sempre mediante o seu ip interno independentemente se a db esta instalada no próprio servidor ou não ou seja em convencao.php vai estar sempre disponível 4 ips, 2 do próprio servidor 1 interno que será sempre usado e outro externo que nunca vai ser usado por ele próprio e os ips externos dos 2 outros servidores. Em relação ao debug obrigado na mesma.

Comment: Afinal o que quer saber? o valor da variavel $dbL? O ip do servidor interno? Porque não está claro qual o resultado que espera. Se quer mais performance pode tirar a validações

Comment: Nada neste momento a questão desta pergunta está respondida e já alterei na minha pergunta de forma que funcione e mais uma vez obrigado por me ter mostrado uma alternativa.